# Get The Value of Single Result Array in CI Model

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, model

i Have this function on my model.

```
function agent_claim($agentcode,$bankname, $accowner, $accnumber){
    $result= $this->db->query("INSERT INTO account (bank, number,name) VALUES ('$bankname', '$accnumber', '$accowner');");
    $accid= $this->db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();")->result();
    $result = $this->agent_account($agentcode, $accid);
    return result;
}
```

The return value of this query must a single value.

```
$accid= $this->db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();")->result();
```

I cant insert in  this syntax

```
$result = $this->agent_account($agentcode, $accid);
```

because the return value is not a number but its an array.
How to get the value of $accid ?

Comment: $this->db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();")->row(); here try row() instead of result(). and you should use $this->db->insert_id() for getting last insert id. Also use active records for insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use active records as below. 
Reference about [Active Records](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)

```
function agent_claim($agentcode,$bankname, $accowner, $accnumber){
        $data = array(
         'bank' => $bankname,
         'number' => $accnumber ,
         'name' => $accowner
        );
    //insert data to acccount table
        $this->db->insert('account', $data); 
    //get your last insert id
        $accid=  $this->db->insert_id();

        $result = $this->agent_account($agentcode, $accid); //this call your other function in model
        return $result;
    }
```